# Get path of virtual environment in pipenv

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

How to can get the `path` of `virtualenv` in pipenv?

can configure it to use a custom path for newly created `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The following should give you the paths

```
$ pipenv --where
/home/wonder/workspace/myproj
```

```
$ pipenv --venv
/home/wonder/PyEnvs/myproj-BKbQCeJj
```

Comment: I also find it sometimes useful to do `pipenv run which python` to make sure I'm using the Python I want to use.

Answer (score 16):

Adding to Sewagodimo Matlapeng's answer for the second part of the question:

> can configure it to use a custom path for newly created virtualenv?

According to [documentation](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-virtual-environment-location), you can set the base location for the virtualenvs with the environment variable `WORKON_HOME`. If you want to place the virtualenv specifically in `<project>/.venv`, set the environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`.

e.g., running:

```
export WORKON_HOME=/tmp
pipenv install
```

Would place the virtualenv in `/tmp/<projectname>-<hash>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the documentation in "Usage" section:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#usage

You can find these two options:

- --where                         Output project home information.
- --venv                          Output virtualenv information.

The option "--venv" gives you the virtualenv path.

Or better here:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#locate-the-virtualenv

BR

Answer (score 0):

I create a command to handle this:

https://github.com/tw-yshuang/Ubuntu-Setup-Scripts/blob/8917578f9ad95be03f48608b7068337215d33f92/config/.customfunction#L12

From `line 12 ~ 105`

```bash
Usage: pipenv_correspond [OPTION]

OPTION:
  ls,  --list                list all the corresponding projects_root & venvs
  uls, --useless             list all the not existing projects_roots that still have corresponding venvs
  npr, --no-project-root     hide projects_root
  rm,  --remove              remove all the venvs from command: "ls" or "uls", deafult is use "uls"

# example
$ pipenv_correspond ls
```

There have some options that suggest you enable this command:

1. **Recommend**, create a `~/.customfunction` file and
   paste it, then use this command:

```bash
$ echo '# customfunction\nsource ~/.customfunction' >> <shell_profile>
```

shell_profile, e.g. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`

2. you can copy this code from `line 12 ~ 105` to your shell_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding mysterious env path of Pipenv, I'd recommend to set `WORKON_HOME`, so that Pipenv will create virtual env within project directory

```bash
export WORKON_HOME=./venv
```

If you insist to, u can use command below (as mentioned by [Sewagodimo Matlapeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802290/10519373)):

```bash
pipenv --venv
```

Answer (score -5):

You can simple use following command:

```
pipenv --where
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. --where gives the location of the project, not the virtualenv.